# JavaFX Application exceptions

Tags: javafx, compiler-errors

When I launch MainApp class, it shows me this:

[image]

When I click "apasa-ma", it gives me these errors, this app should be like a form for registering the sale of the internet package

### The Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Label.setText(String)" because "this.label" is null  at org.example.MainController.handleButtonAction(MainController.java:15)    ... 58 more Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at 
javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)   at 
javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)    at 
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)     at 
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)    at 
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)    at 
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)   at 
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)   at 
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)  at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)  at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)  at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)  at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)     at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)  at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)  at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)     at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)     at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)  at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)     at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)    ... 46 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Label.setText(String)" because "this.label" is null  at org.example.MainController.handleButtonAction(MainController.java:15)    ... 58 more
```

## The Code

**My MainApp Class**:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;import javafx.scene.Parent;import javafx.scene.Scene;import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
    
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exemplu JavaFX");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

**My MainController class**:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;import javafx.fxml.FXML;import javafx.scene.control.Button;import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainController {

    private Label label;
    
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Butonul a fost apăsat!");
    }

}
```

**My InternetPackageController class**:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;import javafx.fxml.FXML;import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class InternetPackageController {@FXMLprivate ChoiceBox<Integer> speedChoiceBox;@FXMLprivate ChoiceBox<Integer> dataTrafficChoiceBox;@FXMLprivate ChoiceBox<Integer> durationChoiceBox;@FXMLprivate TextField uniqueIDField;@FXMLprivate TextField firstNameField;@FXMLprivate TextField lastNameField;@FXMLprivate TextField addressField;@FXMLprivate TableView<InternetPackage> packageTable;

@FXML
private void handleAddButton(ActionEvent event) {
    InternetPackage spackage = new InternetPackage(
            speedChoiceBox.getValue(),
            dataTrafficChoiceBox.getValue(),
            durationChoiceBox.getValue(),
            uniqueIDField.getText(),
            firstNameField.getText(),
            lastNameField.getText(),
            addressField.getText()
    );

    packageTable.getItems().add(spackage);
}

}
```

**My InternetPackage class**:

```
package org.example;

public class InternetPackage {private int speed;private int dataTraffic;private int contractDuration;private String uniqueID;private String firstName;private String lastName;private String address;


    public InternetPackage(int speed, int dataTraffic, int contractDuration, String uniqueID, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.dataTraffic = dataTraffic;
        this.contractDuration = contractDuration;
        this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
    
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    
    public int getDataTraffic() {
        return dataTraffic;
    }
    
    public void setDataTraffic(int dataTraffic) {
        this.dataTraffic = dataTraffic;
    }
    
    public int getContractDuration() {
        return contractDuration;
    }
    
    public void setContractDuration(int contractDuration) {
        this.contractDuration = contractDuration;
    }
    
    public String getUniqueID() {
        return uniqueID;
    }
    
    public void setUniqueID(String uniqueID) {
        this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit the question, fix the formatting.  You shouldn't quote your own text using `> `.  You should format the stack trace as code (just indent the whole thing four spaces).  You shouldn't have different code sections for different components of a class.  Just post the whole code for the class and indent it all by four spaces (the curly brackets saying "code sample" in the stackoverflow editor will do that for any highlighted section).  See [how to format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: `label` is an uninitialized private member of the MainController class.  Why would it not be null?  See [what is a null pointer exception and how do i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).  Perhaps you just forgot to add the `@FXML` annotation to the label declaration so that the `FXMLLoader` can inject the label value when it loads the FXML document.  That presumes the FXML document not shown (`"sample.fxml"`) has an `fx:id` value for a label in the document (e.g. `<Label fx:id="label"/>`.

Comment: Please do not use quotes (denoted by `>` in markdown) for text _that is not being quoted_. Quotes are for words that are not your own words original to the answer; they are _not_ for separating text or styling headers. Please maintain the original format of stack traces when including them in your question. Please follow conventional code formatting—and be consistent with the formatting—when including code in your question. When formatting multi-line code as code, indent each line by four spaces or, what I find easier, fence the code with _three_ backticks (`\``).

Comment: All that advice is to make your question more readable. And a more readable question is more likely to be understood and given a satisfactory answer. In short, you should format your question correctly to help us help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help with formatting.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

Add `@FXML` over the label, so that the FXMLLoader creates an instance of it when it loads the fxml.

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

}
```

**If this does not work:**

Make sure that your fxml file has the `MainController` assigned.

**Extra info about the lifecycle of fxml controller and its nodes:**

1. When you start your application your controller is generally null and all fields inside too.
2. When your application loads a Scene, then it checks if the Scene has a controller assigned.
3. If the Scene has a controller assigned, the application creates an instance of the assigned controller and assigns it to the Scene.
4. While creating the instance of the controller, it checks, if there are any fields with @FXML annotations.
5. For all @FXML annotated fields, there will be an instance created and assigned to that field. Until now, all fields are null.
6. If your Scene is gone, the garbage collector will destroy the controller, because it is not used anymore (sets it to null)